# Custom report in openerp

Tags: report, odoo, openerp-7, rml

How to remove the default name of the report in the print button without editing in the base class, i.e if I click print button, it display Receipt Slip and "GRN" (my custom report), all I need his to remove the "Receipt Slip" (default report name) from the print option without editing in the base class,

Here is my code,
python file
    report_sxw.report_sxw('report.picking.list','stock.picking.in','my_report/report/incoming_shi pment.rml',parser=receipt)

XML file

```
<report auto = "False"
            id="stock.report_stock_picking"
            model="stock.picking.in"
            name="picking.list"
            string="GRN"
            rml="my_report/report/incoming_shipment.rml"
            usage="default"

    />
```

How to hide the "receipt slip" (default report name) and replace my custom report name.

And when I select all the record in the list view while printing, "Failed path too long" message, so how can we change the report name GNR.pdf and remove the invoice number from the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code, it will work

```
<report id="stock.report_picking_list_in" 
        model="stock.picking.in" 
        name="stock.picking.list.in" 
        string="GRN" 
        rml="my_report/report/incoming_shipment.rml"
/>
```

Comment: Viola! it's working, so we need to pass the default receipt slip name in report tag, Thanks